# Cron job is not running automatically

Tags: magento2, cron, magento-cron

I am trying to implement cron job to write a log file with 1min interval. I have an issue while doing the same. I notice that cron job is not running automatically.

Each time when I run "PHP bin/Magento cron: run " then only cron job gets executed and the database gets populated. If each time I need to run that command then it does not serve as the purpose of corn job.

I follow this link to implement:

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/config-guide/cron/custom-cron-tut.html

Please help me for the same

Comment: have you configured cron in crontab?

Comment: Yes I did it.I made crontab.xml in "etc" and .php in the Cron folder

Comment: Did you manage to fix it?

Comment: @RaülVila I am executing the command that you mentioned below

Comment: I typed crontab -e but I dont see anything inside it

Comment: Then put the crontabs there, as the devdocs say, fill them with your information and then run the commands I put.

Comment: Should I put */5 * * * *  this over there and saved it  /var/backups/crontab.tgz and then run your mentioned command for setup:upgrade...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

just run this command in terminal `crontab -e` then paste below code in terminal.

```
* * * * * <path to php binary> <magento install dir>/bin/magento cron:run
```

After pasting that code press CTRL + X key then you will see this message.

**Save modified buffer (ANSWERING "No" WILL DESTROY CHANGES) ?**

Now press `Y` now you will see this type of message.

**File Name to Write: /tmp/{{you will see temp name}}/crontab**
Just press `ENTER` And cron set.

It will call every minute Magento cron and Magento will manage your extension's cron and run as per configured time.

After cron configuration you just need to flush the cache.

Comment: Welcome happy to help you

Comment: I have another query. In php file I extend \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface.Is it possible to   do some other task not related to log?

Comment: not getting you.

Comment: I mean to say, I have a Logegr.php file which has a execute method and this execute method runs each time when cron run and write some "hello" in system.log file.And this .php file is same as mentioned in magento devdocs.Now I want to do some other task like log cleaning.

Comment: yes you can write your custom method at `method="execute"` and create same method in your  php file.

Comment: @kunj, I'm also facing the same issue and tried as you said, but I'm getting crontab: installing new crontab
"/tmp/crontab.QHM7OV/crontab":26: bad minute
errors in crontab file, can't install.
Please help

Comment: are you trying with your user on the server? if yes then try to edit the crontab with that user.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure all the paths are properly written and there are no extra spaces or anything like that:

In the CLI type: `crontab -e` and you should see your crons:

```
* * * * * <path to php binary> <magento install dir>/bin/magento cron:run | grep -v "Ran jobs by schedule" >> <magento install dir>/var/log/magento.cron.log
* * * * * <path to php binary> <magento install dir>/update/cron.php >> <magento install dir>/var/log/update.cron.log
* * * * * <path to php binary> <magento install dir>/bin/magento setup:cron:run >> <magento install dir>/var/log/setup.cron.log
```

You can run:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento index:reindex
php bin/magento cache:flush
```